# How to search a word in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I am struggling to find a certain word in a sentence.
For instance,
If I have a this sentence 'look toward cage again'

```
import re
pattern = r'again'
text = 'look toward cage again'
matchOB = re.search(pattern , text)
if match0B:
   print('True')
```

This code returns True, however

```
pattern = r'aga'
text = 'look toward cage again'
matchOB = re.search(pattern , text)
if match0B:
   print('True')
```

This code also returns  True.
I want to return only if it is completely matched with word not with characters.

It would be really appreciated if it is explained in detail.

Comment: Do you have to use Regex? Since there are ways to do this with just pure Python

Comment: Regex isn't needed here... `if pattern in text.split():`

Comment: Oh I also tried to make sure without Regex , however I did not have that idea to use text.split(). Thank you so much for all !

Comment: But that will not work well with any punctuation, as it will not find the word "punctuation" in this comment. Or "comment" for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern (assuming words can only be comprised of alphabetics):

```
\b[A-Za-z]+\b
```

If you want to match digits too:

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9]+\b
```

- `\b` matches empty string at the end of word
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` matches one or more characters from `[A-Za-z0-9]`

As a side note, if you want to include `_` too, you can use the token `\w`:

```
\b\w+\b
```

Comment: Thank you kind explanation. It is more understandable than other site.

Comment: @user7421972 Happy to help :)